# Editable <span> with centered text

Tags: html, css

I want to have a content-editable `<span>` whose width grow as we type and whose text is centered.
I would like a solution that does not imply Javascript if possible.

As you can see, the text-align property doesn't do anything:

```css
#item {
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span id="item" contenteditable="true">Hello</span>
```

[image]

How should I do?

Comment: give span some min-width

Comment: you are wrong, text-align is working fine and your text is centred

Comment: @TemaniAfif What browser are you on? On Firefox I get something like that https://imgur.com/a/WUldZwf

Comment: add `display:inline-block`

Comment: @TemaniAfif THANK YOU SO MUUUUUUUUUUCHHHHH

Comment: @TemaniAfif Please write an answer I will validate yours. I searched the solution non-stop during the 2 last days.

Comment: @dippas what is the relation of the duplicates with this question? it's not an issue with height or width

Comment: @dippas the width was applied to the body element to create the line break ... it's not an issue with width at all, I can simply put a longer text without adding max-width

Comment: @dippas yes I always question dupes when I don't agree ... there is probably other dupes, but those one aren't [for me]. The op don't want to apply width or height to his element, so the answers are oboviously the same but the problem is completely different. ... But at least I comment before trying to reopen duplicates

Comment: @TemaniAfif better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `span` inline-block:

```css
#item {
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span id="item" contenteditable="true">Hello some text and more teeeexxt some text and more teeeexxt some text and more teeeexxt some text and more teeeexxt some text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```css
#container {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
position: relative;
}

#item {
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><span id="item" contenteditable="true">Hello</span></div>
```

But of course, I wrapped it up in a div to tidy it up a bit

Comment: no need all this, simply move text-align:center from the span to the div and it's done

Comment: Yea, that is also possible >.< But at least it is easier to align multiple elements at once now xD

Answer (score 0):

try to add "display: block;" in css.

```
#item {
  display: block;
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need wrap your span with a `div` and give it `text-align: center` style to achieve what you wanted.

```css
#item {
  border: solid;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <span id="item" contenteditable="true">Hello</span>
</div>
```